# Python3 subprocess code call not working for retrieving list of conda environments installed

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to get a list of conda environments using the following Python code:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("conda info --envs", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

xx = process.communicate()

print(xx)
```

But it simply prints `(b'', b"'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n")`

Interestingly, when I type the same command `conda info --envs` on both Windows command prompt and powershell, it shows me the list of conda environments installed on my machine.

Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) suggest not to use `shell=True` on windows... Maybe try `args` as a list with `shell=False`. **EDIT**: this is not reproducible on my windows machine, it lists all envs either way (list and string, with shell true or false)